# How do I fix my usage of RewriteCond in our MediaWiki .htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, mediawiki

Here's the relevant part of our `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^download.shtml     /en/downloads [R]

# Don't rewrite requests for files in MediaWiki subdirectories,
# MediaWiki PHP files, HTTP error documents, favicon.ico, or robots.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(stylesheets|images|skins)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(redirect|texvc|index).php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/error/(40(1|3|4)|500).html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/robots.txt

# Rewrite http://wiki.domain.tld/article properly, this is the main rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The problem is, we're fighting against the existing MediaWiki rules, and I'm having a hard time telling what's actually going on. The problem seems to be that when we visit download.shtml, it brings us to **a** wiki page, but says "There is currently no text in this page." when actually when I visit the page using `/en/downloads` it does display our downloads page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try adding a condition for your downloads.shtml page so it ignores it in your second rewrite rule. Something like this.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/downloads.shtml
```